# Would it be possible for a non-context-free language L to be context-free under iteration?

Tags: math, theory, context-free-grammar, computation-theory

Language L is not a context-free language.

But could L* be a context-free language?

Comment: Pure-CS questions are better asked on [cs.se]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible.  As an example, consider the alphabet Σ = {1} and let L be the language { 1<sup>p</sup> | p is a prime number }.  You can prove that this language is not context-free by using the pumping lemma.

However, the language L* is the set of all strings except for 1.  The reason for this is that

- ε ∈ L*, because ε ∈ N* for any language N.
- 1<sup>2</sup> ∈ L* because 2 is prime.
- 1<sup>3</sup> ∈ L* because 3 is prime.
- 1<sup>n</sup> ∈ L* for any n ≥ 2, because you can start with either 1<sup>2</sup> or 1<sup>3</sup> and concatenate an appropriate number of copies of 1<sup>2</sup> to it.

This language is indeed context-free, and you can prove that by writing a grammar for it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for repeatedly astonishing me with beautiful mathematical truths :-)

Comment: Thanks! Using  { 1p | p is a prime number } is really brilliant! By the way, would you mind taking time to have a look at my another question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/19282963/2853961

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think it is "1ⁿ ∈ L* for any n ≥ 2" rather than "1ⁿ ∈ L for any n ≥ 2".